# Neighborhoods of skew product maps.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, dynamical-systems, geometric-topology

Let $X_1, X_2$ be real manifolds (endow them with Riemannian metrics if you wish). 
Let $f_1:X_1 \to X_1$ continuous (or differentiable if you wish) with a robust property $A$ on an open neighborhood $\mathcal{U}_1$ of $f_1$.
Let $f_2:X_2 \to X_2$ continuous (or differentiable if you wish) with a robust property $B$  on an open neighborhood $\mathcal{U}_2$ of $f_2$.
Let finally be $f: X_1 \times X_2 \to X_1 \times X_2 / f(x,y)=(f_1(x),f_2(y))$.

I wish to know under what conditions it is possible that, given a neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $f$, it can be reduced until $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{U}_1 \times \mathcal{U}_2$ so that its points project onto the factors satisfying $A$ and $B$ respectively.

I don't think in general this fact to be true as a strict inclusion, but I believe this could be true in a qualitative way. My doubts come specially from the obvious fact that inside $\mathcal{U}$ there are maps that do not respect fibers so it can not be deduced striaghtforwardly.
Furthermore, even when the map could respect fibers it is not straightforward that the property would hold either since conjugacies might not be easy to stablish.

Can anyone give any suggestions on the direction of the answer with recommendations of bibliographical sources? Thanks you all very much.

Comment: I was able to construct what I needed, but relying on strong conditions over $A$ and $B$ properties, I still wish to get further insight on the general answer to my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "robust property"?

Comment: We say that $f$ possesses a robust property $\mathcal{P}$ if there exists a neighborhood of $f$ such that all $g$ in the neighborhood posses the property. You can say that a property is $C^k$ robust by taking the neighborhood in the $C^k$ topology.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{U}=\mathcal{U}_1\times\mathcal{U}_2$? The space of maps between the product is not the same as the product of the space of maps between the factors, i.e. $$C^k(X_1\times X_2,X_1\times X_2)\ncong C^k(X_1,X_1)\times C^k(X_2,X_2)$$

Comment: I know, that is why I am asking if there is any bibliography attending this matter